# Java, How to change GMT time to local time?

Tags: java, time, format, localtime

Server sends me time like this:

> 2012-06-08 17:00:00 +0100

I need to change it like `HH:MM` based on local time. For example this time is what time at Japan, India, US and etc.

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Option 1: using `java.util.Date`/`Calendar`:**

First you need to parse the value to a `Date`, then reformat it in the format and time zone 
you're interested in:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z",
                                                    Locale.US);
Date date = inputFormat.parse(inputText);

// Potentially use the default locale. This will use the local time zone already.
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
```

**Option 2: using Joda Time**

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) is a much better date/time library for Java.

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormat
    .forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")
    .withLocale(Locale.US);

DateTime parsed = inputFormatter.parseDateTime(inputText);

DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormat
    .forPattern("HH:mm")
    .withLocale(Locale.US)
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());

String outputText = outputFormatter.print(parsed);
```

Note that you should only convert to/from string representations when you really need to. Otherwise, use the most appropriate type based on your usage - this is where Joda Time really shines.

Answer (score 0):

Use JodaTime. It's far better and safer than Java's Date and Time API. There are a lot of methods that return a LocalTime object (HH:MM).

As an example, new DateTime(your date time).toLocalTime();

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Date is *always* in UTC. What makes you think it's in local time? I suspect the problem is that you're displaying it via an instance of Calendar which uses the local timezone, or possibly using Date.toString() which also uses the local timezone.

If this isn't the problem, please post some sample code.

I would, however, recommend that you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) anyway, which offers a much clearer API.

Comment: Inappropriate response, and not helpful. The Question does not have a `java.util.Date`, only a String presumably. And no a `java.util.Calendar` is apparently *not* involved as that interface/class does not by default generate output like that seen in the Question. Also, a mere mention of library in not usually a sufficient Answer on Stack Overflow without some explanation and example code.

Answer (score 0):

The other Answers are correct but outdated. Use java.time classes instead.

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Kolkata = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-06-08 17:00:00 +0100" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" ) ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

## Using java.time

Define a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) formatting pattern to match your input String.

```
String input = "2012-06-08 17:00:00 +0100";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" );
```

### `OffsetDateTime`

Parse the String as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object that represents the `+0100` in your input which means “one hour ahead of UTC”.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

Apply a `ZoneId` to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for any desired time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId_Kolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ); // India
ZonedDateTime zdt_Kolkata = odt.atZone( zoneId_Kolkata );
```

…and another…

```
ZoneId zoneId_Montréal = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Montreal" ); // Québec Canada
ZonedDateTime zdt_Montréal = odt.atZone( zoneId_Montréal );
```

### `Instant`

For UTC, extract an `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = zdt_Montréal.toInstant();
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.